# Memory in Javascript, but with fractions

Tags: javascript

There are a few issues with the code below. The original code was written by a gentleman named Adam Khoury, and I have tried to find him, but I am unable to do so. The code creates a visual memory game with letters 'A' through 'L'. I wanted to modify it to apply to fractions. So '1/4' and 25% would match. Or '33%' and '0.33' etc.

I am in way over my head. I am very rusty in javascript and while I understand most of what is happening, I am quite lost about how to make it work.

My solution was as follows. I added a new array "memory_array2" with corresponding values of fractions/decimals/percentages in pairs. I parse both memory_array and memory_array2 to the memoryFlipTile function. The idea was to "show" the second array, but use the values from the first array to match corresponding pairs.

I tried replacing "val" in line 55 with val2, and while that does replace the values in the board with array2, it a) creates them side by side, and b) even if the corresponding tiles are flipped, they do not stay flipped.

I also don't quite understand what the function of memory_values and memory_values.length is exactly.

I DO fully understand how the code clears arrays once two cards are flipped, checks to see if the board is cleared and creates a new board, and flips cards back if they do not match.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#memory_board{
    background:#CCC;
    border:#999 1px solid;
    width:795px;
    height:340px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
div#memory_board > div{
    background: url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    width:90px;
    height:43px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:36px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<script>
    // Scripted By Adam Khoury in connection with the following video tutorial:
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_ohDPWmsM0
    var memory_array = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','G','H','H','I','I','J','J','K','K','L','L'];
    var memory_array2 = ['13%','0.13','25%','1/4','1/3','0.33','0.7','70%','.5','1/2','1/8','12.5%','2/5','40%','3/4','75%','3/5','0.60','20%','0.20','1/10','10%','30%','0.30'];
    var memory_values = [];
    var memory_tile_ids = [];
    var tiles_flipped = 0;
    Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
        var i = this.length, j, temp;
        while(--i > 0){
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            temp = this[j];
            this[j] = this[i];
            this[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    function newBoard(){
        tiles_flipped = 0;
        var output = '';
        memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
        for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
            output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\',\''+memory_array2[i]+'\')"></div>';
        }
        document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
    }
    function memoryFlipTile(tile,val,val2){
        if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){
            tile.style.background = '#FFF';
            tile.innerHTML = val;
            if(memory_values.length == 0){
                memory_values.push(val);
                memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
            } else if(memory_values.length == 1){
                memory_values.push(val);
                memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
                if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]){
                    tiles_flipped += 2;
                    // Clear both arrays
                    memory_values = [];
                    memory_tile_ids = [];
                    // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
                    if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length){
                        alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
                        document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                        newBoard();
                    }
                } else {
                    function flip2Back(){
                        // Flip the 2 tiles back over
                        var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                        var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                        tile_1.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                        tile_1.innerHTML = "";
                        tile_2.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                        tile_2.innerHTML = "";
                        // Clear both arrays
                        memory_values = [];
                        memory_tile_ids = [];
                    }
                    setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="memory_board"></div>
<script>newBoard();</script>
    <p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. What the game is currently doing is comparing string values such as `'E'=='E'`, however you are dealing with percentages/fractions/decimals.

You need to find a way to convert all these values to one type such that they can be compared with each other. Now that type of preference would be the decimal.

Now, what I am about to do it very dirty, and you should find a better way of doing it. I'm going to use `eval`[WARNING MAY BE HARMFUL] to covert the string '3/4' to 0.75.

I'm doing this because I'm lazy, but you could split the string by the `/` and divide the two parts against each other.

```
eval('3/4') == '0.75'  //true
eval('3/4') === '0.75' //false
```

That solves our fraction issue. Now onto percentages. This code will convert from '50%' to 0.5:

```
parseFloat(('50%')/100.0;  //0.5
```

I should only do this percentages, therefore I will check if each number is a percentage before doing that. That leaves us with this code:

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) { return str.slice(-suffix.length) === suffix }

if(endsWith(memory_values[0], '%')) {
    memory_values[0] = parseFloat(memory_values[0])/100.0;
}
if(endsWith(memory_values[1], '%')) {
    memory_values[1] = parseFloat(memory_values[1])/100.0;
}
```

Now, both our `memory_values[0]` and `memory_values[1]` are in either fraction form or decimal form.

Let us compare them(while `eval`ing the fraction)

```
if(eval(memory_values[0]) == eval(memory_values[1])){
    ...
}
```

Here is the resulting, working code: http://pastebin.com/cwSjrsBD
And here it is as a website: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/182097009/working.html

Bug note: `eval('1/3') != '0.33'`
You will need to round your numbers.

Comment: Could you accept it as the correct answer then? Also, do not use eval like I did, and go round out the fraction results.

Comment: This is beautiful. And for now, I will just use fractions that don't have infinite solutions so make things simpler. Yes I will do exactly that in v2.

Answer (score 0):

I think some logic should be changed.

1. I see `memory_array` and `memory_array2` as two different sets of memory.
2. The comparison method should not rely on the content of the memory, just for an example the set can contain some links to pictures, then no comparison can take place.
3. The order of the sets should be kept.
4. Only indices are used for shuffeling and for the comparing.
5. Comparing is done in its own function `isCombination()`.
6. For better testing, I included an `title` attribute in every tile with the contained index.
7. At start, the function `newBoard` expect an array, which is used later, when called without any parameter.

```js
// Scripted By Adam Khoury in connection with the following video tutorial:
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_ohDPWmsM0
var memory_array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L'],
    memory_array2 = ['13%', '0.13', '25%', '1/4', '1/3', '0.33', '0.7', '70%', '.5', '1/2', '1/8', '12.5%', '2/5', '40%', '3/4', '75%', '3/5', '0.60', '20%', '0.20', '1/10', '10%', '30%', '0.30'],
    memory_values = [],
    memory_tile_ids = [],
    tiles_flipped = 0,
    actualMemory;

Array.prototype.getShuffledIndices = function () {
    var indices = Array.apply(Array, { length: this.length }).map(function (_, i) { return i; }),
        i = this.length, j, temp;
    while (--i) {
        j = Math.random() * i | 0;
        temp = indices[j];
        indices[j] = indices[i];
        indices[i] = temp;
    }
    return indices;
}

function newBoard(memory) {
    if (memory) {
        actualMemory = memory;
    }
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = actualMemory.getShuffledIndices().map(function (a) {
        return '<div title="' + a + '" id="tile_' + a + '" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this, ' + a + ')"></div>';
    }).join('');
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile, val) {

    function isCombination(a, b) {
        if (a + 1 === b || b + 1 === a) {
            return (a + b - 1) % 4 === 0;
        }
    }
    function flip2Back() {
        // Flip the 2 tiles back over
        var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
        var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
        tile_1.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
        tile_1.innerHTML = "";
        tile_2.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
        tile_2.innerHTML = "";
        // Clear both arrays
        memory_values = [];
        memory_tile_ids = [];
    }

    if (tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2) {
        tile.style.background = '#FFF';
        tile.innerHTML = actualMemory[val];
        if (memory_values.length == 0) {
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        } else if (memory_values.length == 1) {
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);

            if (isCombination(memory_values[0], memory_values[1])) {
                tiles_flipped += 2;
                // Clear both arrays
                memory_values = [];
                memory_tile_ids = [];
                // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
                if (tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) {
                    alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
                    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    newBoard();
                }
            } else {
                setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
            }
        }
    }
}
// call with the wanted memory, in this case it is possible to select
// between memory_array and memory_array2
newBoard(memory_array2);
```

```css
div#memory_board {
    background: #CCC;
    border: #999 1px solid;
    width: 795px;
    height: 340px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

div#memory_board > div {
    background: url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    width: 90px;
    height: 43px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="memory_board"></div>
```